# CakePHP 2.x i18n validation messages

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, internationalization

5h of fight with this and no results.
i have tried overloading methods with _*d() and _*() and didn't help. shell validation_errors neither.
normal string working well in views but validation messages nope.

default language for app is polish and alt is english.
i have .pot files in Locales/eng/LC_MESSAGES with source strings as polish and translations as english and it works fine

in model before validate

```
public $validationDomain = 'validation_errors';
```

and in AppController in beforeRender

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
```

for force eng lang

anyway, it is default domain for validation...
and it doesn't work

i don't know if i do something wrong or it is bug or sth...

any ideas ??

Comment: Read my article in polish: http://blog.kdev.pl/2013/02/internacjonalizacja-statyczna-i.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'pol');` or `$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'eng');` when using different languages on user level. The `Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');` is a sitewide fallback.

[See this CakePHP cookbook entry for more information.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

Comment: it's strange. so Configure do not affect models? cake takes for that special var in session array? anyway it has helped, thanks a lot